# How to copy the video, covert all audio streams to AC3, and only keep the subtitles in English using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I often use this to convert the audio streams to AC3

`-i input.mkv -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -c:s copy output.mkv`

However, if I only want to keep the English (en/Eng) subtitle(s), given that the subtitles can be multiple languages and they are not sorted in any particular order?  I try to add `0:s:m:language:eng` but I cannot make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `-map 0` with `-map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:s:m:language:eng`:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -c:s copy -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:s:m:language:eng output.mkv`

---

Note that `-map 0` selects all input streams, so we can't use it when mapping selective subtitles stream.